# multiple callback queues

Tags: ros, callbackqueue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using a ROS node to read from several topics calling ros::spinOnce in a loop.

Every time I call spinOnce it checks **every** topic to which the node is subscribed, what I want instead is to check specific topics at different points in my code.
I've seen [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) that I can achieve it using different callback queues, but when it comes to explain how to assign different callbacks to different queues the link refers to subscribers API and I got lost.
Can someone post an example of how to assign, let's say, Callback_1 to queue_1 and Callback_2 to queue_2?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214629/multiple-callback-queues/) by [TheBoris](https://answers.ros.org/users/23212/theboris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a very simple example with the comments inline:

```
#include <ros/spinner.h>
#include <ros/callback_queue.h>

#include <std_msgs/Header.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

// callbacks to be added to internal ROS queue
void headerCallback(const std_msgs::Header::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("stamp.sec: %d", msg->stamp.sec);
}

// callbacks to be added to user queue
void stringCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("string: %s", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_queues");

  ros::NodeHandle n;
  // nothing special for internal ROS queue
  ros::Subscriber sub1 = n.subscribe("/header_topic", 10, headerCallback);

  // define user callback queue
  ros::CallbackQueue string_queue;
  // create options for subscriber and pass pointer to our custom queue
  ros::SubscribeOptions ops =
    ros::SubscribeOptions::create<std_msgs::String>(
      "/string_topic", // topic name
      10, // queue length
      stringCallback, // callback
      ros::VoidPtr(), // tracked object, we don't need one thus NULL
      &string_queue // pointer to callback queue object
    );
  // subscribe
  ros::Subscriber sub2 = n.subscribe(ops);

  // spawn async spinner with 1 thread, running on our custom queue
  ros::AsyncSpinner async_spinner(1, &string_queue);
  // start the spinner
  async_spinner.start();

  while (ros::ok())
  {
    // process one message from ROS internal queue
    ros::spinOnce();
    ROS_INFO("Press Enter to process available messages from ROS internal queue");
    // wait for user input
    getchar();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The custom queue is handled in parallel thread without interruption and handles messages that arrive on `/string_topic`, while internal queue is processed once user presses Enter in terminal. To check it, just publish to these topics from terminal with `rostopic pub`. You will see, that `/string_topic` outputs continuously, but `/header_topic` waits for user input.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheBoris](https://answers.ros.org/users/23212/theboris/) on 2015-07-27**:
thank you, extremely useful!

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-02-08**:
What if I do have a tracked object i.e., the callback functions are members of a class along with the subscribers?

**Comment by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on 2017-03-31**:
This is excellent. Thank you!

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2020-03-25**:
Did someone solve this for tracked objects usage?